# Angular: Content of a disabled input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have a disabled input in a page with angular. It's just an input to match the formatting of its mutable neighbors.  I want to set it to a date.

The model for the data is not formatted.  I would like to pipe it through the `date 'medium'` filter.

The following works but gives an error saying `angular.js:13550 Error: [ngModel:nonassign]`.

```html
<input readonly type="text" name="Date" disabled ng-model="item.date | date : 'medium'">
```

I can see why angular is upset. What would happen if someone enabled the and modified the input, right? But I to want to get the date into the input anyway.  What *should* I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to not to modify it. You can simply do

```
<input readonly type="text" name="Date" disabled value="{{item.date | date : 'medium'}}">
```

Comment: I thought this would work too, but it doesn't. It's probably because `item.date` starts out undefined, and then gets filled in when an http request completes.  I'm guessing that `ng-value` is only evaluated at the beginning.

Comment: @Kenkron I have used `value` instead of `ng-value`. I also tested it and it works. I haven't digged up `ng-value` on how that works. but AFAIK angular does have a binding on every variable and will update it as the value for that changes.

Comment: I just looked up `ng-value` and tried it in angular ***1.1.5*** and it doesn't work, but the same thing works in angular ***1.6.8*** so it might be a version problem.

Comment: Odd.  When I use `<input readonly type="text" name="Date" disabled value="item.date | date : 'medium'">`, it literally.... OH WAIT, I SEE IT.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot the double curly brackets.  This works.

Comment: @Kenkron Yeah, Becaus `value` is not an `ng-directive`